# how can I display the following scenes hierarchy in swift using collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tableview, xib

I have the following  display scenes  available. I am getting confused what type of hierarchy of controls I should take to display these type of view in xib .

[image]

[image]

please give ideas  to show these types of scenes. because my items are coming dynamically . Its not fixed. so if I took tableview to display the first items and its categories then where should i display the rest items.

**Edited**

I took four sections. In 1st section collection and delivery buttons. In 3rd notes and in 4th allergy & checkout .
In 2nd my order items are there. but here I have two level of data.. order item name like chicken kabab small,... etc and 2nd level its addons like plain nan, bottle of drink,... etc. Here  my order items is iterating in cell as well as my addons are iterating.  I took the order items name in  cell. now where should i take the addon items programatically and how to set the size of each cell based on its all contents inside it.

```
class cartVC: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate{

var tableData = ["al","dbd","gdge","kjdkas","al","dbd","gdge","kjdkas","al","dbd","gdge","kjdkas","al","dbd","gdge","kjdkas"]


var mainview = UIView()

@IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func backBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func changeColor(sender:UISegmentedControl){

    switch(sender.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 0:
        print("collection clicked")
    case 1:
        print("delivery clicked")

    default:
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 4
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var rowcount = 0
    if section == 0{
        rowcount = 0
    }
    if section == 1 {
        rowcount = tableData.count
    }
    if section == 2{
        rowcount == 0
    }
    if section == 3{
        rowcount == 0
    }

    return rowcount
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    if section == 0{
        let headerView = UIView()
        //set the frame
        let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        // headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60)
        headerView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.minX , frame.minY, frame.width, 60)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //Initialize segment control
        let items = ["Collection","Delivery"]

        let customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0


        //set the frame amd segmented control
        customSC.frame =  CGRectMake(frame.minX + 10, frame.minY + 5, frame.width - 20, 30)

        // style the segmented control
        customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        customSC.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        customSC.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        //add target action method
        customSC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CartViewController.changeColor(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        //add subview
        headerView.addSubview(customSC)

        //Add label
        let headinglbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: frame.minX + 10, y: frame.minY + 40, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20))
        headinglbl.text = "Your Order"
        headinglbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
        headinglbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        headinglbl.textAlignment = .Center
        headerView.addSubview(headinglbl)

        mainview = headerView

    }

    if section == 2{
        let totalView = UIView()
        totalView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60)
        totalView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        //Add discount label
        let discount = 14.5
        let discountlbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 20))
        discountlbl.text = "Online Collection Discount(\(discount)%)"
        discountlbl.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        discountlbl.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        discountlbl.textAlignment = .Left
        totalView.addSubview(discountlbl)

        //Add discount price

        let discountprice = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width-60, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 20))
        discountprice.text = "£ 1.27"
        discountprice.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        discountprice.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        discountprice.textAlignment = .Left
        totalView.addSubview(discountprice)

        //Add label
        let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 20, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        lbl.text = "Total"
        lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        lbl.textAlignment = .Left
        totalView.addSubview(lbl)

        //calculate amount label
        let totalAmountLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(totalView.frame.width-70, 20, totalView.frame.width, 40))
        totalAmountLbl.text = "£ 0.0"
        totalAmountLbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
        totalAmountLbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        totalAmountLbl.textAlignment = .Left
        totalView.addSubview(totalAmountLbl)

        mainview = totalView

    }

    if section == 3{
        let footerView = UIView()
        footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 200)
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        //Add note label
        let notelbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, tableView.frame.size.width, 20))
        notelbl.text = "Leave a note"
        notelbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
        notelbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        notelbl.textAlignment = .Left
        footerView.addSubview(notelbl)


        //Add  a note textview
        let noteTxt =  UITextView()
        noteTxt.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, footerView.frame.width-20, 50)
        noteTxt.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        noteTxt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
        noteTxt.text = "e.g.  Instructions about yout order"
        noteTxt.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        noteTxt.delegate = self
        footerView.addSubview(noteTxt)


        // Add allergy button
        let allergyBtn = UIButton(type:.System)
        allergyBtn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 20)
        allergyBtn.setTitle("Do You have any allergy ?", forState: .Normal)
        allergyBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
        allergyBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "", size: 10)
        footerView.addSubview(allergyBtn)

        // Add checkout button
        let checkoutBtn = UIButton(type:.System)
        checkoutBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 140, 100, 40)
        checkoutBtn.setTitle("Check out", forState: .Normal)
        checkoutBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        checkoutBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "", size: 10)
        checkoutBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        checkoutBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        footerView.addSubview(checkoutBtn)


        mainview = footerView
    }

  return mainview
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cartcell")! as! CartTableViewCell


    cell.itemLabel.text = tableData[indexPath.row]



    return cell
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var heightCount:CGFloat = 0
    if section == 0{
        heightCount = 60.0

    }
    if section == 2{
        heightCount = 60.0

    }
    if section == 3{
        heightCount = 200.0

    }
    return heightCount
  }
```

**My customcell code**

```
 import UIKit

 class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


let padding: CGFloat = 5
var background: UIView!
var itemLabel: UILabel!
var priceLabel: UILabel!
var deleteBtn:UIButton!




override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    selectionStyle = .None

    background =  UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    background.alpha = 0.6
    contentView.addSubview(background)

    deleteBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
    deleteBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "deleteBin.png"), forState: .Normal)
    contentView.addSubview(deleteBtn)

    itemLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    itemLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    itemLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(itemLabel)

    priceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    priceLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(priceLabel)

}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    background.frame = CGRectMake(0, padding, frame.width, frame.height-2 * padding)
    deleteBtn.frame =  CGRectMake(padding, (frame.height - 25)/2, 40, 25)
    priceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width-100, padding, 100, frame.height - 2 * padding)
    itemLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(deleteBtn.frame) + 10, 0, frame.width - priceLabel.frame.width - CGRectGetMaxX(deleteBtn.frame) + 10, frame.height)
}

}
```

Comment: Table view with sections. You could probably house your pickup/delivery in the first, and the ordered items in the next section, and in your last section you can include the charges.

Comment: ok but  here in items section the ordered  items  again have its sub items as you can see using + sign and  its repeation based  on the order selection. so here if i put  the items in cell  in 2nd section as you told  then where should i put the subitems based on count  @GoodSp33d

Comment: I would go with a Collectionview, it's easier to adapt do diffrent needs then tableview.

Comment: can you send some demo sample for it.. I think collectionview  is better for  photos gallery@Vaionixx

Comment: tableview and collectionview are almost same  with few changes@Vaionixx

Comment: You can add stackView to prototype cell. A stack view can grow according to its content. Constrains it so that cell size grows with it. Create a UIView with labels and add it as subview to stackView.

Comment: can you give us some sample code for  constraint it  so that  cell size grows  with it.@K.Nimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As our mates already said about using tableview and sections, Here we gonna follow the same way.Since it is a broad topic to explain i'll give some hint and at last you can find link for demo project.

- First add a tableview in your storyboard then add **collection**,**Delivery** & **Your order** objects as tableview **header**
- Create a new class subclass of `UITableviewcell` with `xib` let's name it as **Cell1**.Now add **delete icon**, **main dish** label and **price** label,for sub items we gonna use another `UITableview`.
- Now create another `UITableviewcell` with xib name it as **Cell2**, prepare that xib for sub items and their price.
- In cell1 `numberOfSectionsInTableView` return number of **main dish** count and in `numberOfRowsInSection` return 1, Now load name of all main dishes in their respective label's
- Upto now we having some number of section(depending on number of main items) each section having one `UITableview`.
- Now we have to change height of tableview cell **dynamically** depending on **SubItems count**. so in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` i have added following lines

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     let subItems = tableContainer![indexPath.section].valueForKey("additional_items") as! NSArray
     var defaultCellHeight:CGFloat = 37//Consider 37 as height of cell without subitems

     //Following for loop keeps on increasing defaultCellHeight depending on available count
     for _ in subItems  {
         defaultCellHeight += 37
     }
     return defaultCellHeight + 20
  }
  ```

  Since it is hard to explain everything deeply i have provide code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.While looking into the demo project you'll understand everything

**NOTE :** Upto now we have loaded all main dishes details, and we have provided enough room for upcoming sub item's.

- In **Cell1** class add tableview delegate and datasource in `awakeFromNib`,add all datasource methods as required.set `numberOfSectionsInTableView` as **1** and `numberOfRowsInSection` as **subitem count**
- That's it we have loaded tableview **dynamically** as per your requirement.
- Now at last add **discount**, **total**, **leave a note**& **Checkout** objects in separate `tableviewcell` class an load it at last index.
- Or add add all those objects inside a `UIView` and add it as `Main tableview's` footer.

**NOTE :** The above hints are just for reference, For better clarification of concept i have added a [demo project's github repo](https://github.com/gokulgovind/DynamicTable).

**RESULT :**

[image]      [image]